# Javascript show more/ show less with speed effect

Tags: javascript, performance, toggle, hide, show

i have this javascript code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

it is possible to add a toggle speed effect for show and hide?

Comment: You mean like [jQuery's fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/BLkpG/

Comment: And you don't want to use jQuery, is that it?

Comment: Im wondering if it possible to add effect to my code?

Comment: How about using css transition for height and changing it from 0 to auto, for example?

Comment: No i dont want to use css transition in this case, i think i will use jquery instead javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Effect to you code will result you to add more code line for Browsers Compatibility.
I suggest you to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), It will save you lot of time developing and testing.

Comment: Yes maybe it's best solution, i think i will use jquery instead javascript, thanks.